# Unit tests and testing the test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

My app has the ability to update an item.  I would like to create a unit test for this.

This is in c# using Moq.  When I call the setup method in mock.  I am having it take an existing item, and then update it as needed.

```
messageMock.Setup(m => m.SaveMessage(It.IsAny<Message>()))
           .Callback((Message msg) =>
{
    var oldMsg = _messages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == msg.MessageID);
    if (oldMsg != null)
    {
        oldMsg.Description = msg.Description;
        oldMsg.IsActive = msg.IsActive;
        oldMsg.Name = msg.Name;
        oldMsg.Type = msg.Type;
    }
}).Verifiable();
```

and the method under test is:

```
public void SaveMessage(Message message) 
{ 
    var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); 
    message.ModifiedBy = windowsIdentity != null ? 
                         windowsIdentity.Name : 
                         string.Empty; 
    message.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now; 
    Messaging.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Modified;        
    Messaging.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

If the logic of updating the item is done in Moq, then I am just testing the test.  How can I test the business logic of update functionality?

Comment: Post the code for the method you want to test!

Comment: @user721146 I add the method into your question, however the method looks like the method you want to `mock` instead of the method you want to test.

Comment: You should mock the objects that your class-under-test is calling; in this case you want to mock whatever object is referred to by `Messaging`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no direct answer to your question.

Your problem is that your message class violates the sine responsibility principle -  either by doing several things at one (executing validations,  saving to database,...)  in one class or by tight coupling.

Unit testing does not work well with that sort of code. In order to be able to unit test your save method you will need to extract all aspects into individual units (eg classes) and then test them individually.

That way you will end up with one class for validation,  one class  for doing the actual saving, your domain object and so on. These classes are then composed together to form the entire thing.

Now you can test each of these classes individually and you will probably find that the only thing you need to mock away is the actual writing process.

Comment: The message class only saves

Comment: In the above source code,  only Messaging.saveChanges() does actually save. The rest is probably the business logic that you would want to test,  right?

Comment: @Matthis Huttar - Yes

Comment: Then the way to go would be to move all the other lines to a new class that is in charge of "touching"  the message before persisting and then write a test for that class.

Comment: That makes sense.  Would I then make an interface for the persistence class?  Then mock the persistence class in my tests?

Comment: This could be one way.  What the best practice (in Java at least -  not a c++ expert)  is to use constructor overloading. You'll have your regular constructor and a second one that gets all regular Paramus plus the objects it depends on. The regular constructor will just call the extended one instantiating all dependencies like the validator. This will be the constructor you use in your production code.  In your test code you just use the extended one,  passing all the mocks. Depending on the capabilities of your mocking framework using interfaces might not be necessary.